# How to calculate PRF in OpenSSL?

Tags: openssl

I'm developing a EAP-TLS server using OpenSSL. I need to derive key material from TLS session as described in RFC5216.

Key_Material = TLS-PRF-128(master_secret, "client EAP encryption", client.random || server.random)

I can get master secret in TLS connection by visit SSL_SESSION->master_key, but how could I calculate PRF by OpenSSL?

Comment: Because I can't answer my question, I can just add comment. I just get the answer from the OpenSSL user mailing list. There is a patch to OpenSSL recently. you can find it on this link sctp.fh-muenster.de/dtls/tls-exporter.patch . People have the same question as me can refer to the patch's implementation. And can anyone post an answer for this?

Comment: Why can't you answer your own question, afaik this is not prohibited by SO ;-).

Answer (score 1):

I just get the answer from the OpenSSL user mailing list. There is a patch to OpenSSL recently. you can find it on this link [sctp.fh-muenster.de/dtls/tls-exporter.patch](http://sctp.fh-muenster.de/dtls/tls-exporter.patch) . People have the same question as me can refer to the patch's implementation.

Comment: from this comment, it appears that client_random and server_random are made available from `ssl3_state_st->server_random` and `ssl3_state_st->server_random`, where `ssl3_state_st` is `s3` member of `SSL` (where you got `SSL_SESSION`) - thanks!